# How does Visual Studio 2010 successfully link with a library that is not in the link list

Tags: visual-studio-2010, linker

How does Visual Studio 2010 successfully link with a library that is not in the link list?  I am building a .dll call it user.dll, that depends on a .dll call it required.dll.
In Visual Studio required.lib is NOT in Properties | Linker | Input | Additional Dependencies.
The most interesting thing, is that this behavior is not consistent, it fails on our CI Build Machine.

I have tried cleaning and rebuilding both 'user.dll' and 'required.dll' and it still works on my local machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming C or C++ here. There may be a directive like:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "required")
```

in one of your source files. That would cause required.lib to be linked in.